# No NgModule metadata found for 'AppServerModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular9

I am trying to run and build my server side rendering angular project. Once I have the project running locally on my machine and open it in a web browser I receive the following error:

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppServerModule'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22963:27)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22066:47)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:28255:55)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:28236:40)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:28196:41)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:339:35)
    at CommonEngine.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/bundles/express-engine.umd.js:95:69)
    at step (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:57)
    at /Users/user/Projects/myproject/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:75
```

I have done some checking and research but I am having trouble finding where the problem is. I am sure it is something relatively simple but would appreciate any help. I will provide some details about a few other files. Thank you in advance!

Here is the src/main.server.ts file

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

Here is the src/app/app.server.module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

'import' instead 'export' will fix it

Comment: can't believe I didn't see that. looking at code too much today, ill let you know how I go

Comment: if there is anything else I will help you np :D

Comment: Thanks. So I did try it but from my research
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
is valid and needs to be in the main.server.ts
Strange issue, I am using Angular 9 but perhaps something is going very wrong somewhere

Comment: can you add this in main.ts and check?

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Comment: Just checked that file and the code is already existing in the DOMContentLoaded Event Listener. Double checking the logs

Comment: No luck yet, only additional information is server 500 error. I am checking other parts of the code

Comment: seems strange at this point i would try deleting node_modules and reinstalling maybe some bug in dependencies

Comment: Very strange. Going to have to keep investigating. I reinstalled the node_modules with no luck

Comment: Got it working, had to change build technique to run it via a firebase function locally instead of serving it outside of a firebase function

Comment: I have the same kind of issue..

`Unhandled Promise rejection: No NgModule metadata found for 'e'. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'e'`

Comment: @TravisKnight i have come across the same issue, could you please elaborate what you mean by "had to change build technique to run it via a firebase function locally instead of serving it outside of a firebase function"

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with ng10 univeral project. In my case I had turned bundleDependencies to false, and reverting it to true cleared up the above error. angular.json snippet below.

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/server",
    "main": "server.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
    "bundleDependencies": true
  },
```

Comment: came across the same issue in version12, but in my case bundleDependencies is true by default, and still the issue persist.